# Creating a Counter for user input C#

Tags: c#

Hey guys I need some help creating a counter for user input based on how much time they enter a guess to guess a random number from 1 - 100. So far this is what I have but it only output 1 count and does not count the next input. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GuessingGameGUI
{
    public partial class frmGuess : Form
    {
         public frmGuess()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmGuess_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblCount.Visible = true;
        lblHowMuch.Visible = true;

    }

    private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtGuess.Text = "";
        lblCount.Text = "";
        lblHowMuch.Text = "";
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
        txtGuess.Focus();
    }

    private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int target = r.Next(0, 101);

        int userGuess = int.Parse(txtGuess.Text);

        int guessCount = 0;

            if (userGuess == target)
            {
                guessCount++;
                this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkOliveGreen;
                lblHowMuch.Text = "You guess the right number " + "it took you: " + guessCount.ToString() + " guesses";

            }
            else if (userGuess < target)
            {
                guessCount++;
                this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;

            }
            else if (userGuess > target)
            {
                guessCount++;
                this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

            }

        lblCount.Text = "You made: " + guessCount.ToString() + " Guesses";

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you are setting the guess counter to zero every time `btnCheck` is clicked. You need to make sure it is reset only once per guess session.

So this means that you need to move `guessCount` out as a class-level variable and make sure that you only reset it at the first run of the form and whenever `btnReset` is clicked.

Here's how I would refactor your code to achieve this:

```
public partial class frmGuess : Form
{
    public frmGuess()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmGuess_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblCount.Visible = true;
        lblHowMuch.Visible = true;
        ResetData();
    }

    private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ResetData();
    }

    private Random r = new Random();
    private int guessCount;
    private int target;

    private void ResetData()
    {
        guessCount = 0;
        target = r.Next(0, 101);
        txtGuess.Text = "";
        lblCount.Text = "";
        lblHowMuch.Text = "";
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
        txtGuess.Focus();
    }

    private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int userGuess = int.Parse(txtGuess.Text);
        guessCount++;

        if (userGuess == target)
        {
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkOliveGreen;
            lblHowMuch.Text = String.Format(
                "You guessed the right number it took you {0} guesses",
                guessCount);
        }
        else
        {
            this.BackColor = userGuess < target
                ? System.Drawing.Color.Yellow
                : System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }

        lblCount.Text = String.Format(
            "You made {0} Guesses",
            guessCount);
    }
}
```

You'll also notice that you were resetting the `target` each time `btnCheck` was clicked. That too needed to be moved to a class-level variable.

It's also a good habit to get in to making instances of `Random` a class-level variable too as there are circumstances where you can end up with less-than random numbers if you don't.

You'll notice that I moved all of the reset code into a new `ResetData` method that can get called both when the form loads and when `btnReset` is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be so obvious.  Why are you setting  int guessCount = 0 in btnCheck_Click?  Why don't you keep a global counter?

Comment: I see what you are saying but how do I keep a global counter?

Comment: Lot of options.  You can keep user's scores in external file or database.  You can keep it in-memory in the form that launches frmGuess.  Depends on your requirements.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question. This is more like a comment. Please either edit this to make it an answer or delete it.

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm not too sure about that. An answer doesn't necessarily need to have a full explanation of the issue to be acceptable. I'll agree that it *could be improved* however.

Comment: Okay I'm trying to understand what you guys are saying but what I am trying to do is when ever the user enter a number and lick the button it display the amount of time they guess. That's why I have it in the button click. But doesn't it have to be in my if statement or a loop?

Comment: I am not sure why you would need an IF or loop here.  It appears you just want to maintain a running counter of how many times the "Check" button was clicked.  Just make sure to reset the counter on click of Rest button (btnReset_Click).  If this is a simplistic application, a global variable at class level should suffice your purpose.

Comment: @jdphenix - SO is about creating a repository of quality questions with quality answers. This isn't a quality answer.

Comment: I think the person asking question just wanted to know what he/she was doing wrong - a full coding solution was not asked for.  I pointed out what was wrong and how it could be resolved.  The question was very simple so a detailed answer with coding sample was never required.  Don't we expect people asking questions to do a bit of home-work? Sometimes - only pointers are enough.

Comment: @murtazat - I agree that a "full coding solution" may not be needed, but asking two questions as a way of answering is not the right way. You answer is not solely for the benefit of the OP - it's for the entire SO community. Please don't make the answer hard to interpret.

Comment: My bad being a new member.  Will follow the SO etiquette in future.

Answer (score 0):

To make it global, take out `int guessCount = 0;` from the `btnCheck_Click` function and put it at the top where it appears like:

```
namespace GuessingGameGUI
{

    public partial class frmGuess : Form
    {

    int guessCount = 0;
```

That way `guessCount` won't be continually reset to zero and then incremented each time you press the `btnCheck` button.

Comment: You can't have variables in namespaces, only within classes.

Comment: woops, put it in the wrong spot. I re-edited and put it under the public partial class. Good catch!